# The limit of a sequence of $n$ elements

Tags: calculus, limits

I remember seeing this a while ago, but now I can't remember the process, can someone guide me?

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac1{n+2n^2}+\frac2{2n+2n^2}+\frac3{3n+2n^2}+\cdots+\frac{n}{n^2+2n^2}\right)$$

Comment: Upper/Lower Sums, let $t = 1/n$. Does that help?

Comment: It helps to have an idea, I'm gonna google more about that.

Comment: $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{k}{kn+2n^2} = \sum_{k=1}^{n} (\frac{1}{n} - \frac{2}{k+2n})$

Comment: We have $\frac{k}{kn+2n^2}=\frac{1}{n} \frac{\frac{k}{n}}{\frac{k}{n}+2}$.

Comment: And hence $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x}{x +2}dx$, completing the problem. Perhaps I should assemble the pieces?

Comment: You guys are great, I'm gonna try to assemble the pieces myself, but just in case I'd appreciate if you did as well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partition $[0,1]$ into $n$ equal parts. Next, consider the summand,

$$\left(\frac1{n+2n^2}+\frac2{2n+2n^2}+\frac3{3n+2n^2}+\cdots+\frac{n}{n^2+2n^2}\right)$$

Extract $1/n$ from the whole thing, this yields

$$\frac{1}{n}\left(\frac1{1+2n}+\frac2{2+2n}+\frac3{3+2n}+\cdots+\frac{n}{n+2n}\right)$$

Now we can clearly see that this can be written as

$$\sum_{i = 1}^{n}\frac{1}{n} \left ( \frac{i}{i + 2n} \right)$$

Divide the top and bottom by $1/n$ and we get

$$\sum_{i = 1}^{n}\frac{1}{n} \left ( \frac{i/n}{i/n + 2} \right)$$

Taking $n \to \infty$, we recognize that this is equivalent to the integral

\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x}{x + 2} dx &= \int_{0}^{1} \frac{x + 2 - 2}{x +2} dx \\
&= \int_{0}^{1} 1 - \frac{2}{x+2} dx \\
&= 1 - 2[\log(3) - \log(2)] \\
\end{align}

Comment: Is the last step obtained by an analytical process? Do I have to figure out a pattern in all the exercises? Or do usually these sequences have the same possible integrals as 'equivalent' forms? Sorry for the dumb question

Comment: We partition the interval $[0,1]$ into $n$ equal parts, i.e, $P = \{0, 1/n, 2/n, \dots, i/n, \dots, 1 \}$. So I used the definition of an Upper sum here. There are no dumb questions!

Comment: Should probably note that $f(i/n) = \frac{i/n}{i/n +2}$.

Comment: And why [0,1]? (Sorry for those types of questions but I should have kept my notes)

Comment: Because $t_i - t_{i-1} = i/n - (i - 1)/n = 1/n$

Comment: See edit, hope that helps.